# How to set fixed spaces between ticks in maptlotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

I am preparing a graph of latency percentile results. This is my pd.DataFrame looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
result = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(133000, size=(5,3)), columns=list('ABC'), index=[99.0, 99.9, 99.99, 99.999, 99.9999])
```

I am using this function (commented lines are different pyplot methods I have already tried to achieve my goal):

```
def plot_latency_time_bar(result):

    ind = np.arange(4)
    means = []
    stds = []

    for index, row in result.iterrows():
        means.append(np.mean([row[0]//1000, row[1]//1000, row[2]//1000]))
        stds.append(np .std([row[0]//1000, row[1]//1000, row[2]//1000]))

    plt.bar(result.index.values, means, 0.2, yerr=stds, align='center')


    plt.xlabel('Percentile')
    plt.ylabel('Latency')
    plt.xticks(result.index.values)
#     plt.xticks(ind, ('99.0', '99.9', '99.99', '99.999', '99.99999'))
#     plt.autoscale(enable=False, axis='x', tight=False)
#     plt.axis('auto')
#     plt.margins(0.8, 0)
#     plt.semilogx(basex=5)
    plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)


    fig = plt.gcf()
    fig.set_size_inches(15.5, 10.5)
```

[And here is the figure:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYFfX.jpg)

As you can see bars for all percentiles above 99.0 overlaps and are completely unreadable. I would like to set some fixed space between ticks to have a same space between all of them.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverlfow! Please try to reduce your question to a minimal example and verifiable, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. In short you should have an example that contains only your problem, and that one can run independently (without for example relying on your data).

Comment: Try to use x-axe labels as strings and not as numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using pandas, you can do all this from within that library:

```
means = df.mean(axis=1)/1000
stds = df.std(axis=1)/1000
means.plot.bar(yerr=stds, fc='b')

# Make some room for the x-axis tick labels
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not wishing to take anything away from xnx's answer (which is the most elegant way to do things given that you're working in `pandas`, and therefore likely the best answer for you) but the key insight you're missing is that, in `matplotlib`, the x *positions* of the data you're plotting and the x tick *labels* are independent things. If you say:

```
nominalX = np.arange( 1, 6 ) ** 2
y = np.arange( 1, 6 ) ** 4

positionalX = np.arange(len(y))
plt.bar( positionalX,  y )  # graph y against the numbers 1..n
plt.gca().set(xticks=positionalX + 0.4, xticklabels=nominalX) # ...but superficially label the X values as something else
```

then that's different from tying positions to your nominal X values:

```
plt.bar( nominalX, y )
```

Note that I added 0.4 to the x position of the ticks, because that's half the default width of the bars `bar( ..., width=0.8 )`—so the ticks end up in the middle of the bar.